# PBR texture showing up on the wrong side of plane

Tags: texturing, pbr

I'm rather new to PBR textures, so this question might seem dumb.

So, when i put a pbr texture onto my model, it showed the underside of the texture instead of the top on the side which is visible.

**The side where it is supposed to be but has the underside of the texture show up instead:**
[image: visible side shows wrong texture]

.

.

**The top, which is not visible, has the texture displayed correctly:**
.

[image]

How do i go about fixing this? I can't flip the planes.

Comment: Is the normal of this face pointing correct way?

Comment: Blender uses OpenGL shading, and your normal maps may be DirectX based. If this is the case, there is a simple conversion you can do to fix it.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Im pretty sure its showing uo fine and is doing what it is supposed to. My problem is that i want to change the side the texture is facing

Comment: Push..............................